Term for Marsupial with Offspring in Pouch
Is there a term for a marsupial that has a offspring in its pouch? 'Pregnant' doesn't sound right, cause she has already given birth to the offspring. But this is still a distinct life-stage for the offspring, so I feel like there should be a word that refers to it. 'Carrying' would work, but it is also used to refer to pregnant non-marsupials, so it would just cause confusion. Is there a better term available?

They definitely aren't pregnant at that point (well, not unless they have another one in the pipeline), as they have given birth.
Carrying is often used as it is generally clear that you are talking about a particular species or group of animals.
Another term that is fairly commonly used is "Pouch Young" (e.g. use in last line under "Hit by car" at a wildlife rescue org). This is generally not used to refer to the baby animal rather than the mother though as in a sentence like "Do they have pouch young?".
I think the proper term would be "in marsupium", the marsupium being the pouch for which the group Marsupial is named. Of course, some other animals, such as isopods, and even the a family of plants (the liverworts) have marsupia, so depending on the context, this might not be much help.
